# how to set Enums in @nestjs/mongoose schema

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

This is my schema and I want to set the role to enum

```js
@Prop({ required: true })
name: string;

@Prop({ required: true })
email: string;

@Prop({ required: true })
password: string;
  
@Prop()
role: string;
```

This is how I used to do in mongoose

```js
role: {
  type: String,
  enum: roles,
  default: 'user',
}

const roles = ['user', 'admin'];
```

Answer (score 20):

The proper way to set enums is the following:

```js
    @Prop({ type: String, enum: Role })
    role: Role
```

or:

```js
    @Prop({ type: String, enum: Role, default: Role.User })
    role: Role
```

This way you achieve both `Mongoose` schema validation and `TypeScript` runtime data validation.
If you omit the config inside the `@Prop()` decorator you could possibly insert any value into the `role` field by casting it to the Role enum:

```js
    {
      role: 'blabla' as Role
    }
```

**PS:**
In the previous versions of `NestJs` you must list the supported enums inside an array. See this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/issues/745).

Comment: For those curious, this was implemented in Mongoose directly, rather than NestJS specifically. See this PR: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/9547

Comment: what should we do if we want to store roles instead of one role?

Comment: @Sekomer I suppose you should define it as the documentation recommends:
`@Prop({ type: [{ type: String, enum: Role }] })
owner: Role[];`
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb

Comment: thank you @Dezzley. I've found it after asking, unfortunately the syntax is pretty ugly :D

Answer (score 9):

you need to make an enum first:

```js
enum Role {
  User, //or User = "user",
  Admin, // or Admin = "admin",
}
```

and then set it as the datatype

```js
@Prop()
role: Role
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can assign:

**src\constants\api.enums.ts**

```js
export enum ROLES {
 USER,
 ADMIN,
 SUPER_ADMIN,
}
```

**src\schemas\user.schema.ts**

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ROLES } from '../constants/api.enums';
import { IsEnum } from 'class-validator';
    
@Schema()
export class User {
 @Prop({ type: String, enum: ROLES, default: ROLES.USER })
 @IsEnum(ROLES)
 roles: string;
}
export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```